# Put content between the layout in the bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3. I want to include the content (including 3 images) in the middle of the width of the red frame.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZyrYq

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row me">
        <div class="col-lg-3 many-cols-centered">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 many-cols-centered">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 many-cols-centered">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    border:solid 1px red;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box
}
.me{text-align:center}
.many-cols-centered {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;padding:0
}
```

Comment: You have to be more specific. Also, Your link to a CodePen should be accompanied with code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?[image]

If so you could do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row me">
  <h>Hello my  friend</h>
  <div "col-lg-12">
   <div class="col-lg-3 many-cols-centered">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300">
   </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 many-cols-centered">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300">
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 many-cols-centered">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```